# In pyspark, how to partitionBy parts of the value of a certain column when using df.write.partitionBy(..).save?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I want to partitionBy date instead of time in my Spark Dataframe, how can I do that?

Suppose I have dataframe with the first column as datetime, like '2019-06-25 12:00:00', '2019-06-25 11:00:00', etc. I know how to partion it by time, but I don't know how to partition it by date.

```py
spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()

df = spark.sparkContext.parallelize([
    Row("2019-06-25 12:00:00", "2"), Row("2019-06-25 11:00:00", "a"),
    Row("2019-06-24 02:03:10", "2"), Row("2019-06-22 08:00:00", "b"),
    Row("2019-03-12 08:01:34", "3")]).toDF(["datetime", "val"])
```

```
+-------------------+---+
|               date|val|
+-------------------+---+
|2019-06-25 12:00:00|  2|
|2019-06-25 11:00:00|  a|
|2019-06-24 02:03:10|  2|
|2019-06-22 08:00:00|  b|
|2019-03-12 08:01:34|  3|
+-------------------+---+
```

I want to use such methods as

```
df.write.partitionBy(substr('datetime', 10)).save(path='...', mode='...')
```

to achieve my goal, but apparently the above won't work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spark: save DataFrame partitioned by "virtual" column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35437378/spark-save-dataframe-partitioned-by-virtual-column)

Comment: so the answer is no?  @user10938362

Comment: As far as I know.

Comment: A not very elegant solution is to add a new column that contains `substr('datetime', 10)` and partition on that one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this kind of Situation's you can simply add a new column based on your "datetime" field let's say "date_only"

The snippet for your code will be like

1) Register your Dataframe either from source SQL or any flat file system etc. In this case let's consider this below sequence.

```
df = spark.sparkContext.parallelize([
    ("2019-06-25 12:00:00", "2"), ("2019-06-25 11:00:00", "a"),
    ("2019-06-24 02:03:10", "2"), ("2019-06-22 08:00:00", "b"),
    ("2019-03-12 08:01:34", "3")]).toDF(["datetime", "val"])
```

2) Preparing up a new Dataframe from the source one this will allow you to have a new column and the existing column won't be gone from your resultant files in the Partitions.

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as func
partitioned_df = df.withColumn("date_only", func.to_date(func.col("datetime")))
```

3) Saving the data in Append mode into those partitions.

```
partitioned_df.write.partitionBy('date_only').save(path='dbfs:/FileStore/tables/Temp', mode='append')
```

4) I tried the following in Databricks and the Taxonomy looks like this:

[image: Databricks File System - LS result]

5) Also the Parquet (Snappy) file contains the result like this:

[image: Sample file Partitioned in Parquet format]

Kindly let me know if this resolves your problem.