# Spark Parquet partitioning: Can I partition by a value of a given Map element?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, parquet

I would like to save my DataFrame to a Parquet file in a Hive table...but I would like to partition that DataFrame by the value of a specific map element (which is guaranteed to be present).

For example:

```
case class Person(name: String, attributes: Map[String, String])

val people = Seq[Person](Person("John", Map("birthDate"->"2019-12-30", "favoriteColor"->"red")),
                         Person("Lucy", Map("birthDate"->"2019-12-31", "favoriteFood"->"pizza")),
                         Person("David", Map("birthDate"->"2020-01-01", "favoriteMusic"->"jazz"))).toDF

//pseudo-code, doesn't work                 
//people.write.format("parquet").partitionBy("attributes[birthDate]").saveAsTable("people")
```

I can get around it by promoting this value to a top level field and joining (see below), but it would be nicer to avoid that. In addition to avoiding the join overhead, our users are expected to query on attributes[birthDate], so it would be advantageous to partition directly on that field, and not a separate top-level field.

Is there a way to directly partition on that value, without needing temporary DFs/joins?

```
val justNameAndBirthDate = people.select($"name", $"attributes"("birthDate")).withColumnRenamed("attributes[birthDate]", "birthDate")
val newDfWithBirthDate = people.join(justNameAndBirthDate, Seq("name"), "left")

newDfWithBirthDate.write.format("parquet").partitionBy("birthDate").saveAsTable("people")
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spark: save DataFrame partitioned by "virtual" column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35437378/spark-save-dataframe-partitioned-by-virtual-column)

Answer (score 0):

One way is to create a column to partition by it and name it as you wish.

```
val df = people.withColumn("attributes[birthDate]", $"attributes"("birthDate"))

scala> df.show(false)
+------+------------------------------------------------+---------------------+
|name  |attributes                                      |attributes[birthDate]|
+------+------------------------------------------------+---------------------+
|John  |[birthDate -> 2019-12-30, favoriteColor -> red] |2019-12-30           |
|Lucy  |[birthDate -> 2019-12-31, favoriteFood -> pizza]|2019-12-31           |
|David |[birthDate -> 2020-01-01, favoriteMusic -> jazz]|2020-01-01           |
+------+------------------------------------------------+---------------------+
```

It will sure duplicate the data, but it'll do the trick

Then you can partition as you wish:

```
df.write.format("parquet").partitionBy("attributes[birthDate]").saveAsTable("people")
```

**Checking output table**

```
  scala> spark.sql("select * from people").show(false)
    +------+------------------------------------------------+---------------------+
    |name  |attributes                                      |attributes[birthDate]|
    +------+------------------------------------------------+---------------------+
    |David |[birthDate -> 2020-01-01, favoriteMusic -> jazz]|2020-01-01           |
    |Lucy  |[birthDate -> 2019-12-31, favoriteFood -> pizza]|2019-12-31           |
    |John  |[birthDate -> 2019-12-30, favoriteColor -> red] |2019-12-30           |
    +------+------------------------------------------------+---------------------+



spark.sql("desc people").show(false)
+-----------------------+------------------+-------+
|col_name               |data_type         |comment|
+-----------------------+------------------+-------+
|name                   |string            |null   |
|attributes             |map<string,string>|null   |
|attributes[birthDate]  |string            |null   |
|# Partition Information|                  |       |
|# col_name             |data_type         |comment|
|attributes[birthDate]  |string            |null   |
+-----------------------+------------------+-------+
```